# VPN connection failed because service stopped unexpectedly

Tags: vpn, services, cisco

After

1. `sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc`
2. Import my `.pcf` file
3. Try to connect to the VPN and get the following error:

> The VPN connection 'PRUEBA' failed because the VPN service stopped unexpectedly

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue and although I was unable to 'import it' I was able to re-create it with the same information from the PCF file. It worked well: Ubuntu 13.04 64Bit
VPNC and Network Manager Connecting to Cisco VPN device.

Answer (score 15):

This might not answer your question, but check if the option in the 3rd pic is enabled. If not enable it & connect again.

[image: Screenshot: Edit Network Connection]

[image: Screenshot: Open Advanced Options]

[image: Screenshot: Enable MPPE]

Comment: I have the same issue and this solution didn't work, any help?

Comment: this solution helped me on Ubuntu 16.04. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Linux Mint 19 and it work for me.

1. Disable your firewall (`sudo ufw disable`)
2. Disable your ipv6

For Red-Hat system :

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

For Debian system :

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the following at the bottom of the file :

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After all, restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had not updated the VPN password to the system-wide password, which I had changed meanwhile.